# Why Python code doesn’t take variables’ values?

Tags: python, integer

```python
import random

x = input(" minim radom range:")
z = input("maxrange")

print(random.randrange(x, z))
```

Comment: use code blocks to post code

Answer (score 0):

you need to use int() while getting input as following:

```
import random

x = int(input(" minim radom range:"))
z = int(input("maxrange"))

print(random.randrange(x,z))
```

Answer (score 0):

this happens because "input" gets the value from user as string so you need to convert it to int

```
x = int(input(" minim random range:")) 
z = int(input("max range"))
```